# How to find the start and/or end timestamp when a setinterval function is fired or is about to end

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp, setinterval, tampermonkey

I try to write a script in Tampermonkey for a website I often visit, in order to log the movements of my ships.
There is a table generated from the website that has the current movements and the code is like this:

```
<table class="movements_table">
<tbody>
    <tr id="moveInfo815198" class="own">
        <td><span title="Arrival time">1D 8h 3m</span></td>
        <td class="ships">200</td>
        <td class="quantity">200,000</td>
        <td title="Origin" class="source">Town1</td>
        <td title="Target" class="target">Town2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="moveInfo815199" class="own">
        <td><span title="Arrival time">5D 3m 42s</span></td>
        <td class="ships">50</td>
        <td class="quantity">50,000</td>
        <td title="Origin" class="source">Town1</td>
        <td title="Target" class="target">Town2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

From the web developer tools, I realised that the tags: table, tr and span are updated every second.
I assume that they are updated with a setInterval function and that this function must have an endtime timestamp for each movement (line of table).
My problem is that I don't know where to look for these timestamps in the code, in order to log the exact arrival time of each of my movements.

The result I expect to have is a javascript array (i.e. movements) that has as many items as the movements (lines of the table), where each item of this array will be a another array . Each of these arrays would include the following items:

```
[id,timestamp,ships,quantity,origin,target]
```

By parsing the above code, the result would be the following:

```
var movements = [
                 [815198,endtimeofsetInterval1,200,200000,Town1,Town2],
                 [815199,endtimeofsetInterval2,50,50000,Town1,Town2]
];
```

The items **endtimeofsetInterval1** and **endtimeofsetInterval2** should be in milliseconds and they should be written somewhere inside the HTML code.
An easy solution would to convert the arrival time from Days,Hours,Minutes,Seconds to Milliseconds and adding the now milliseconds.
The problem with this solution is that the arrival time gives each time just three parts of it like the first movement (1D 8h 3m).
So if I convert the previous to milliseconds this would be 86400000 but it might also be 86459000 or sth in between because the seconds of the arrival time are not displayed.
This means that the **endtimeofsetInterval1** that I want to log, won't be the correct one and there might be up to 59 seconds missing from the calculation.
That's why I want to find the real timestamps that are used to update the tags of the above table.

P.S. I am interested just for Google Chrome compatibility of my script.

Is there a way to find out where these items are in HTML code?

Comment: No, there is no timestamp just because `setInterval` (or similar) is used.  **IF** a "timestamp" exists, it must be in the page's HTML and/or the page's AJAX calls. ... **What, exactly, is your expected result?  Mock it up in HTML code that you add to this question.**  Are you trying to convert the "Arrival time"s to something like "Thu May 10 2018 10:25:03 GMT+0700"?  If so, be very precise about the timezones involved.  It would be best if you also provided a link to the target page.

Comment: I just explained in detail (I believe) for the result I am expecting after logging the data of the table. Hope it is more properly understandable.

Comment: **IF** there is a "real timestamp" at all, sent to (or on) that page, it will be in the page's XHR calls.  Open up the console and go to the network tab to see those.  We can't help you find it unless we see the page.

Comment: The page is the game **Ikariam** and the movements table in the military advisor.

Comment: That game looks like it uses Flash, which greatly complicates things.  And we would have to create an account and play to where we could see the page you are referencing -- which is way too much for an SO question. ... Also per the **terms of service: `Usage of software or scripts in order to gain advantages at the expense of other players is not allowed. This includes bots, macros and other automatisms.`**

Comment: The only flash in the game are the videos it uses, nothing else. The script I am refering is just for personal use and because I want to have the data of my movements. Anyway, sorry for asking.

Comment: Well, that might be okay then.  But, for that particular website, we can't discover the XHR for you.

Comment: Well I have an account on the Test Server of Ikariam: https://https://test-en.ikariam.gameforge.com with username **PanTester** and password **123456789**. If someone can and want to help, login and fire a movement from Town1 to Town2 with 100 wine and see the XHR.

Comment: Okay, it looks like the page only updates from the server once a minute (when there is no user interaction) and in addition, the arrival time is given as `3m 09s <newline> (loading) <newline> 2:44:42`.  Where `2:44:42` appears to be the time you want and does not change.  So I'm still not clear on what you're after.  Also, nothing seems to be more accurate than to one second, so why do you think that milliseconds matter?  I know how to generate your `movements` array, except for the `endtimeofsetInterval1` bit.  But it seems like there should only be one entry for any given movement.

Comment: Well, 2:42:42 is not the time I want as it is the time that the shipment will end loading and I want the time that it will arrive to the destination. If you fire 2 movements from the same town and the second is fired before the first has finished loading then the second keeps on saying loading but the correct would be waiting or queued and after the loading of the first it should be loading. Each of these 3 phases display the current phase endtime, that's why I want the timestamp that generates the countdown and not the given time under it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170823/discussion-between-panos-and-brock-adams).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but you can simply ask JavaScript for your current time, set `timestamp` attribute for your element and update it as followed:

```
function getTimestamp() {
  return new Date().getTime();
}

setInterval( ()=>{
  let element = document.getElementById('moveInfo815198').setAttribute("timestamp", getTimestamp())
}, 1000)
```

or

if you want to update the time of arrival, you need to know exact date and time of the arrival, for example- 20 May 2018 13:45:25. Then you can simply create function that is going to count for you numbers of hours, min, sec  from the current time.

Comment: First, I don't want to create a timestamp attribute for each movement, I want to find it in the code and I don't know where to look for it. Second, I don't want to update the time of arrival and I don't know the exact arrival time, I just want to find it in a timestamp format in milliseconds and log it JSON with the rest information of each movement.